# Compare two columns in 2 files and replace another column using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

```
$ cat input2 

0105|195267|99/99/9999|

0115|195719|77/77/7777|

0125|195505|88/88/8888|

0135|195719|00/00/0007|


$ cat input1

0105|195267|0|Header|StefenStarts|DIY|06/28/1984|6000|$1656.0000|$1656.0000|$0.0000|
0125|195505|0|Header|StellarCollar|DIY|01/01/1900|6000|$284.0000|$284.0000|$0.0000|
0115|195719|0|Header|DamoranKinsley|DIY|05/14/1980|6000|$5328.2500|$5328.2500|$0.0000|
```

Expected output:

```
0105|195267|0|Header|StefenStarts|DIY|99/99/9999|6000|$1656.0000|$1656.0000|$0.0000|
0125|195505|0|Header|StellarCollar|DIY|88/88/8888|6000|$284.0000|$284.0000|$0.0000|
0115|195719|0|Header|DamoranKinsley|DIY|77/77/7777|6000|$5328.2500|$5328.2500|$0.0000|
```

When the first and second column of file input1 matches with the first and second columns of input2 then the 7th column of input1 file is replaced with the dates present in the 3rd column of file input2.

This awk command works but it checks only for the second column. I need to check for combination of first and second column. Can anyone pls help on this.

Tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$2]=$3; next} $3==0 && $4=="Header" && $2 in A{$7=A[$2]}1' FS="|" OFS="|" input2 input1
```

This gives incorrect output for the 3rd row since it checks only for the second column. It should actually check as combination for both first and second columns.

```
0105|195267|0|Header|StefenStarts|DIY|99/99/9999|6000|$1656.0000|$1656.0000|$0.0000|
0125|195505|0|Header|StellarCollar|DIY|88/88/8888|6000|$284.0000|$284.0000|$0.0000|
0115|195719|0|Header|DamoranKinsley|DIY|00/00/0007|6000|$5328.2500|$5328.2500|$0.0000|
```

Any inputs please..??

Answer (score 1):

Try Below. I hope it helps.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1,$2]=$3; next} $3==0 && $4=="Header" && ($1,$2) in A{$7=A[$1,$2]}1' FS="|" OFS="|" input2 input1
```

Comment: Many thanks @Vidya.. It works so perfect as expected

Answer (score 1):

- use option `-v` to set variable on command line or in `BEGIN` section
- you specify **1st** and 2nd field but only store value in array for 2nd field with `A[$2]`

Here with the correction:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}FNR==NR{I[$1"|"$2]=$3;next}$1"|"$2 in I && $3==0 && $4=="Header"{$7=I[$1"|"$2]}1' input2 input1
```

Comment: I would write `I[$1 FS $2]` and `$1 FS $2 in I` so you don't have to keep repeating the pipe. Also, it's valid to define awk variables between the script and the files, but I don't like that style either.

Comment: Thanks @NeronLeVelu.